# How to access span tag which is on the master page from content page's code behind?

Tags: asp.net

I have written the code in ASP.NET AJAX to authenticate and authorize the user.

Now, if the user role doesn't have permission to access certain resource, then at login time only I want to show some message in one span tag which is on the master page. I want to do This from contnet page only.

Hence how can I access the span tag which is on the master page from content page's code behind.

I cannot use runat="server" for my span tag, why because, it is affecting the existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way is to expose a public property (say `Message`) in master page for capturing the message. In master markup, you can use it within span such as

```
<span><%= this.Message %></span>
```

In content page, cast the master page to master's code-behind class and set the property to whatever value you wish:

```
((MyMaster)this.Master).Message = "bla bla...";
```